# When I try to run my Codeigniter application with 'php spark serve' this message appears "Could not open input file: spark"

Tags: php, codeigniter, xampp

I was tasked to maintain an application developped with Codeigniter 3 and php 5, noting that I've never worked with Codeigniter before.

When I tried to run the server from the command prompt locally using the line `php spark serve` , here's what I get :

`Could not open input file: spark`

Btw, I use Xampp and php 8

These are all the folders of the application :

[tree folders image of the website without spark file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwH8N.png)

As you can see, there is no file called "spark" which may be the reason why the server doesn't run as it is suppose to. However, I was told that the website ran well when it was online.

I still haven't modified any thing in the code because I don't want to mess anything knowing that the application was fully functionnal when it was online.

what should I do to run it on my pc ?

Comment: I think `CI- 3` does not have `spark`.

Answer (score 2):

`php spark serve` is only available with CodeIgniter 4. For CodeIgniter 3, you can use `php -S localhost:8080` command line in the `index.php` directory (which is generally the root folder of your project). **8080** is the port, and you can replace it by any available port if needed.

You will also need to edit your `application/config/config.php` file to make `$config['base_url']="http://localhost:8080/"`. But for peace of mind, and to avoid having to edit it when changing environments (EX: staging, production), it's better to use environment variables ([Set up environment variables with CodeIgniter 3](https://odnualam.com/posts/how-to-set-up-a-env-file-in-codeigniter-3/)).

Hope it helps you.